# SEND LONG JSON POST REQUEST USING ONE SINGLE CSV FILE ON JMETER

Tags: csv, post, jmeter, request

Hi have a csv file REQUEST.CSV on which there exist 1000 register and I want to send it through a post method using Jmeter.
I have been trying many solutions and I dont want to use like 1000 .txt files with every JSON post.

There is a way to use just a .csv file considering that the JSON structure has a lot of parameters?

Thank you!

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Please shar more details on the _many solutions_ you have been trying and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a payload from file - go for [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) directly in your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler body data:

[image]

If there are JMeter Functions or Variables inside the .CSV file and you want them to be resolved to their respective values - wrap it into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval)

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)